# Is there any way to save file on AWS server(without S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, swift5, xcode11.6

I want to save/upload file on Amazon server.
Our web team already do this process, They are using path like : C:\XYZProject\Homescreen\10_03_2020_Hello.xlsx

Can any one help me how to save like the above path on amazon server using Swift 5 code.

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue? You can simply save the files in your public path like you do like in a shared hosting. Make sure you have enough storage space in your AWS instance.

Comment: I don't have knowledge about this, before this I have only upload video using S3 swift code.

Comment: you have line of code for this complete process.

Comment: you can check this out https://fluffy.es/upload-image-to-server/#swiftcode

Comment: Can you please define: 
What I need to replace with
https://catbox.moe/user/api.php 
let fieldName = "reqtype"
let fieldValue = "fileupload"

And Where I need to AWS credentials to upload file.

Answer (score -1):

How to upload file on FTP server in swift 5